# Сравнение строк через оператор switch Java

Tags: java, android, строки, switch, equals

Мне нужно сравнить значение, которое находится в объекте с каждым значением из подготовленного массива.
Как мне это сделать? В моем случае выдает какую-то непонятную ошибку

```
    String text = textView.getText().toString();
    switch (text) {
        case labelsStr[0]:
            startActivity(new Intent(context, Color.class));
            break;
    }
```

Comment: а почему свичом, а не циклом или стримом?

Answer (score 1):

Так как в `java` `switch` по строке добавили в версии 7, то в android `switch` по строке работает начиная с API 19 KitKat (в этой версии собственно и добавили поддержку java 7).

Если точнее, то запускаться будет и на более ранних версиях (на 18 точно), но компилировать нужно как минимум с sdk версии 19 и jdk 7.

Вот необходимая конфигурация:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 19
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }
}
```

Comment: Не особо помогло, пробовал в IntelliJ, такая же шляпа, можно просто пример на Java?

Comment: Для переменных в case не будет работать. Только для констант.